# “Awaiting EE Decision” in Manuscript Central – what does it mean?

Tags: journals, peer-review, editors, journal-workflow

I submitted my paper to a journal twelve days ago. In Manuscript Central, there were some changes of the paper’s status during the first two days, and as far as I can remember, these were *Awaiting ADM Processing* and *Awaiting technical editor selection.* At the third day, I saw *Awaiting EE Decision* which is still there.

From some previous posts I assume that such decision status is normally shown for a paper that is already reviewed by peers. Given that, it’s been only twelve days since my submission and the paper has not been sent out for peer-review yet, what could be the possible implications of the status? Just a bit curious and worried as well.

Comment: The "EE" abbreviation should stand for "Executive Editor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I must also point out before you read the rest of the answer that the Editorial decision has not come yet and this is likely the Editorial decision after minor processing (sorting, subject headings, keyword checks(maybe/maybe not)) and a Technical editor shortlisting it for further review when the editor decides on how to proceed (EE decision)

This is now Obviously the Editorial Decision. He can send it for review if it is a blind peer to peer review journal or reject it outright. Thus the EE decision would be completed by the editor or designated person after going through the paper and deciding if he has to send it to a reviewer, if he has reviewers for the subject matter, if he can return directly to the author for modifications/rewrites or if he wants to accept it for publication(unlikely without a blind peer to peer review.